# How to get -4 working date form particular date in sql

Tags: oracle

below is my requirement
I have from_date and to_date.

I need to fetch -4 working date form to_date eg: jun-30 is the to_date . from that -4 working date is 24th.
how to achieve this in sql.

Thanks.

Comment: hello ram , welcome to SO , what have you tried so far for this

Comment: Does the requirement always same? i.e., subtract -4 to given date or it can vary ±N?

Comment: Hi Arun - The requirement always be same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this out -

```
SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN WEEKDAY( (SELECT orderDate  FROM orders WHERE OrderDate = date() -  4) ) < 5  THEN  
      (SELECT OrderDate  FROM orders WHERE OrderDate = date() -  4 )

     WHEN WEEKDAY( (SELECT orderDate FROM orders WHERE OrderDate = date() -  5) ) < 5  THEN  
      (SELECT OrderDate  FROM orders WHERE OrderDate = date() -  5 )

    ELSE
       (SELECT OrderDate  FROM orders WHERE OrderDate = date() -  6 )
END
FROM orders ;
```

Comment: Hi Ashish,
My actual requirement is, i have table in that i have period start_date and end_date.
i need to exclude weekend and holidays. and need fetch start as from_date and -4 working days as to_date in that.

Comment: For holiday also i have table so if end date = holiday then it should take -1. two consecutive days falls into holiday then to date should be again -1.
so actual end-date 30 so -4 26. if 26 and 25 holiday then 24 should be to_date.

Comment: yes , that is why i added case , try and see if you can derive your logic from this

Comment: Weekday function is not supported in oracle BI. is there any other method we can achieve this.

Comment: you tagged as mysql ,thats why i gave mysql - instead of week day you can use -

Comment: select to_char(sysdate,'d') as day_of_week from dual;  - try to fit this in query

Comment: Hi Ashish, the beow code i have tried . thic code is checking for first holiday.
eg. -4 days from end_date is may 25. may25 is holiday then date will be 22. what if 22nd also holiday. how check in loop.

Comment: Hi Ram , that is why i added case , if it is still holiday - it will go in next when

Comment: your final query will be something like mine only , but you need to figure out what function will be there as per DB specific